# Cron Script Not Working

Tags: scripts, cron

I'm trying to run a cron job that runs a script to print a message in a terminal every minute.

The script is really basic just to test the idea:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

This is what I have in my crontab:

```
* * * * * /etc/cron.hourly/script1.sh
```

I triple checked the script has the correct permission (755) so I don't understand why it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you looking for the output? Does making a file instead work?

Comment: Nothing to do with the script not working, but you shouldn't put your script in /etc/cron.hourly/ otherwise it will be run hourly (and every minute as configured in your crontab)

Answer (score 1):

cron jobs are not associated with any terminal. The output is either thrown away or possibly to mail to the user (if that is configured).

Best to redirect the job to a file then open a terminal to read the file as it is written as in:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World">/home/myname/script1.sh.out 2>&1
```

which will send the output and errors to a file. Better would be to send the whole script output to a file if multiple commands as in:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
exec >/home/myname/script1.sh.out 2>&1 
echo "Hello World"
```

or do it in the crontab as in:

```bsh
* * * * * /etc/cron.hourly/script1.sh>/home/myname/script1.sh.out 2>&1
```

From a terminal, you can run "tail" to display the output as it occurs:

```bsh
tail -f /home/myname/script1.sh.out
```

Comment: Hi Jpezz. Thanks for all the help. It makes much more sense now. I'm still having issues for some reason. Here's my script.sh file from /cron.hourly:
#!/bin/bash

exec >/home/mach01/script1.sh.out 2>&1 
echo "Hello World"

Here is the crontab config: * * * * * /etc/cron.hourly/script.sh>/home/mach01/script1.sh.out 2>&1

btw, I renamed my script to "script.sh"

Comment: I see no info on what your issue is now. Looks like some of your comment got chopped off.

Comment: The issue is that the script still doesn't work.

Comment: Was there anything in the .out file?